# Should an object with a pointer to its parent have a copy constructor defined?

Tags: c++

If an object A contains a member Object B and Object B has a pointer to its parent Object A, do I need to specify a copy constructor for Object B?

Assume there is no dynamic allocation.

Furthermore, does the rule of 3 apply here?

Comment: If `B` doesn't have any ownership of `A`, then no.

Comment: I would recommend asking this on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Well, should a copy be made? If so, should it have the same parent object automatically?

Comment: Run like hell from this design. Having a pointer to one's parent just means the object design is bad.

Comment: Unanswerable without context. What does copying Object B _mean_? Should the copy also be a child of Object A? Even though it's not a member? Seems kinda weird buddy....

Comment: @SergeyA: Meh, it's not _that_ bad. It's just a generalisation of passing a policy. An overgeneralisation, granted.

Comment: Why does a child have a pointer to the parent, when the parent content is with the child (as one complete object)?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, I have seen several attempts at this. Neither one went well.

Comment: @SergeyA: All my attempts have gone pretty well.

Comment: Actually no they haven't I just remembered the utter hell that is my unit test suite never mind

Comment: @SergeyA would a doubly linked list be considered?

Comment: That is a cycle (chicken and egg)

Comment: Bad design? Thing is - you get a different answer from different people here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724092/is-it-bad-practice-for-a-child-object-to-have-a-pointer-to-its-parent

Comment: I suppose the question is - what will happen without specifying such a constructor?

Comment: It depends what you wan't to archieve. If every object B need to have another copy of allocated A (or whatever you do with that pointer), then you should write it. Else, well, no.

Comment: @flkes, where in classic implementation of double-linked list do you have child classess storing pointers to their parent objects?

Comment: You could break the cycle by holding a weak_ptr instead. In that context, copying is fine, though be sure you understand the potentially brutal ramifications of multiple objects sharing any kind of ownership, even weak. There would be potential lifetime tracking problems in this scenario.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your design implements composition with a bidirectional navigation. This can be perfectly valid.
However, as Sergey pointed out in the comments, such a design is not without problems.

Suppose you have a class `Object` and a class `Container` that contains an `Object`.  Here some fundamental questions:

```
Container c;
Object mo1; // Q1: should this be valid ? (i.e. is an object without parent allowed 
Object mo2 = c.o;  // Q2: is this acceptable ?  Q3: Who is parent of mo2 ?
```

Look at questions Q2 and Q3:  if such initialization is acceptable, then the immediate question is what parent do you want:

- if `mo2` should have no parent, you need a copy constructor according to rule of 3, to clear the parent.
- if `mo2` should refer to the same parent (although it is not a member), you could keep the default copy constructor.

Example:

```
struct Container; 
struct Object{
    Container *parent;  
    Object (Container *p=nullptr) : parent(p) { cout << "construct object"<<endl; }
    // copy constructor or compiler generated one depending on Q2+Q3
    ~Object() {}
    ...
};
struct Container {
    Object o;
    Container() : o(this) {}
};
```

If such initialization is NOT acceptable, you should forbid copy constuction explicitely in the code.

```
Object (const Object &o) = delete;
```

**Important note:** *the `Container` might also need a copy constructor. Whatever you decide for `Object`, you might have to deal with in the `Container` if it has to be copiable. In no way could you use there the copy constructor of the `Object`.*

**Important note 2:** *the `Container` might itself be used in more complex situations. Take the example of a `vector<Container>`. When new containers are added to the vector, relocation might be performed, which could invalidate the pointers if you didn't provide a Container copy constructor that takes care !*

Comment: thanks - its stuff like this which make me want to stop programming altogether!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should think about implementing a copy constructor even if the child object doesn't manage any handles or pointers to resources (which will be blindly shared with a copy without such a constructor leading to familiar problems which you clearly understand).

The reason for this is that the copy of a parent's child is not necessarily considered that parent's child!

If the copy of a child is considered to be under the same parent, and the parent has a list of children, whose responsibility is it to insert into that list? It has to be done somewhere. If it's not done in the copy constructor, then every place in the code where a copy is performed has to remember to take some additional action, like `copy.register_with_parent()`. Any place where this is forgotten is quite probably a bug.

If the copy of a child is not considered to be under the same parent, a naive member-for-member copy will have a parent pointer anyway. What is an object doing with a pointer to a parent which is not actually its parent? Something has to clear that pointer, or set it to some "default parent of all orphaned child objects" or whatever. This would be done in the copy constructor.

If you don't know the answers to these questions, then define a copy constructor which is not implemented, so that copying doesn't take place until you do know what the behavior should be. So, copy constructor again, albeit declared but not defined!

Answer (score -1):

Oh, but parent object can't have it's derieved class object unless allocated with pointer:

```
class B;

class A
{
    B son;
};

class B : public A
{
    A* parent;
};
```

Results:

```
field 'son' has incomplete type 'B'
     B son;
       ^
```

Then, if you did it with allocation:

```
class B;

class A
{
public:
    A(void);
    ~A();
private:
    B* son;
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    B() {} // <-depends what you want to archieve
private:
    A* parent;
};

A::A(void) : son(new B) {}
A::~A() {delete son;}
```

Questions arise at this point. Do you want the parent pointer to point to global object `A`, allocate it's own `A` object, or to point to `this` ?

Global variable - no need to write copy constructor:

```
// A class not changed
A global;
class B : public A
{
public:
    B() {parent = &global;}
...
```

If object allocates it's own `A` object, then you need to stick to rule of 3 (or 4). What more, your class `A` needs to stick to this rule too, since we will copy parent object, so every `B` object has it's own:

```
class B;

class A
{
public:
    A(void);
    A(const A& other);
    A& operator=(const A& other);
    ~A();
private:
    B* son;
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    B() : parent(new A) {}
    B(const B& other) : parent(new A(*other.parent)) {}
    B& operator=(const B& other);
    ~B() {delete parent;}
private:
    A* parent;
};

A::A(void) : son(new B) {}
A::A(const A& other) : son(new B(*other.son)) {}
A& A::operator=(const A& other)
{
    delete son;
    son = new B(*other.son);
    return *this;
}

B& B::operator=(const B& other)
{
    delete parent;
    parent = new A(*other.parent);
    return *this;
}

A::~A() {delete son;}
```

And finally, object `B` points to the same object base class, no need for anything special like with global variable:

```
class B;

class A
{
public:
    A(void);
    ~A();
private:
    B* son;
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    B() : parent(this) {} // pointless, but yeah, nothing else is needed.
private:
    A* parent;
};

A::A(void) : son(new B) {}
A::~A() {delete son;}
```

It's not about what should be done and what shouldn't. It all depends what you want to achieve.

Comment: they meant parent/child as in 'contains', not 'inherits', it seems. if you're suggesting that B should inherit from A and _also_ hold a pointer to an A, what is the difference between these two As? i hope they're not the same object! anyway, usually people would do this the other way round, so the child is fully declared before the parent then composed as a member of the parent, whereas the child only gets a reference/pointer to a (forward-declared) parent

Comment: @underscore_d That is my question! Well, you got me here, but notation A and B is widely used for class inheritance, so i fell in this trap.

Comment: i think the general consensus is that parent/child describes composition, whereas inheritance is described as base/derived. sorry, but despite probably not being related to the OP, would these contrived examples be useful for any real scenario? you say "It's not about what should be done and what shouldn't", but then suggest global variables and raw owning pointers, two things advised against/not appropriate for 99% of situations!

Comment: I know it shouldn't be done, and I don't do it ever, but question included those features due being unclear. With normal classes you don't even ever need to stick to rule of 3, if you faithfully stick to standard library.

Comment: @underscore_d - yeh, i should have been clearer. i meant contains not inherits